# What is the benefit of upvoting a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Since the person who made a comment on an answer or a question, if the comment is upvoted by someone showing that this adds some significance to the post. What is the actual use of upvoting a comment? Is it to show that the one who voted also has the same thought as the person who wrote it or something else?

Comment: A major benefit of comment upvoting is avoiding duplication. If I have something to ask or say about a post, and see a similar comment already there, I upvote it instead of adding my own comment. It's less typing for me, and readers know that N other people agreed with the comment.

Comment: You can just glance at the comments and know the important ones ... comment prioritization for your own ease, so to speak

Comment: But what if someone gets answer from just comments only??
What to do then. So no setting is there to indicate this comment gave me the answer that I want. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036374/validate-select-dropdown-with-javascript#comment69283185_41036374 .
See comments on the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the type of comment, but it generally means "I agree", "this is helpful" or "lol"

Good comments come in multiple flavours:

- a improvement/alternative/suggestion to a post
- an external link
- politely pointing out an error in the answer and/or interpretation of the question

Short lived (due to removal flags), but still good

- a request for more information/explanation/refinement
- quality humour

Comment: I agree this is helpful lol

Comment: Also, when there are lots of comments, not sure of the threshold, the comments are collapsed with the highly voted comments taking prominence.