# Why were all the comments removed on this question?

Tags: support, comments, specific-question, meta

So I noticed something odd about a **[popular question about the definition of a cool comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284403/what-is-a-cool-comment?cb=1)**, it seems recently all the comments on that question where removed. Even the comments that had *90+* and *20+* up-votes. Was there a reasoning behind this? I understand when there are too many comments in situations some are removed or cleaned up, but I have never seen a complete wipe before.

Comment: "I have never seen a complete wipe before" - you must be new here. And the reason why the comments were removed should be obvious as most of them were misguided attempts at being funny; which translates to being noise. SO is not reddit; meta.SO is a bit more relaxed than the main site but that doesn't mean that spamming the comment section of a crap question is now accepted behaviour. BTW, there have been actually harmful instances of comment wipes on controversial questions with useful comments - in this case however it was purely cleaning up the crap.

Comment: @l4mpi Don't take everything serious! the question itself was funny and needed some examples! Moreover, some comments were useful while cool! wasn't it what the OP asked? cool useful comments?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284220/when-should-you-upvote-a-comment and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265899/what-is-the-benefit-of-upvoting-a-comment - comment upvotes are different than normal upvotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The summation:

- The purpose of Stack Exchange is to provide meaningful answers to questions.
- Comments which do not further this purpose are considered noise.
- Noise is not useful.

  - SE is not reddit

    - This is especially true for SO
    - While meta.SO is generally more relaxed than SO, it still follows the preceding principles
  - The comments in question were largely directed at humor and discussion not the stated purpose of education.

Therefore:

- Noise was removed.

Coincidentally:

- The thread was being forwarded to a moderator
- Moderators have ultimate cosmic power

Comment: You missed one bullet point: One of the posters was a moderator that got notified of *every single* pointless comment that got posted on his answer. ;P Just imagine having "I'm a useless comment! Please delete me!" pop into your inbox 20 times.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6LD6ITN2dk

Comment: @animuson *One* of the moderators, hmmm?

Comment: I wish you had closed or wiped the question itself, It's hard to see that question and not posting a cool comment! I am serious!