# Why were comments on this question removed?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-comments

Why were several comments (one up voted 100+ times) on this question removed?
[Optimize ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239625/optimize-ternary-operator)

The comments were giving life to the question. [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) please restore the comments.

I don't agree calling those comments as noise according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284630/why-were-all-the-comments-removed-on-this-question) answer if that was the reason you deleted them.

[Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo)/[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)
Regarding dispute on tags:

1. There wasn't any edit summary posted by editors who removed the disputed tag. (Add a feature so that users are forced to write a summary)
2. I wasn't aware of the etiquette of discussing it at Meta.

Comment: Comments are temporary, transient second-class citizens of Stack Overflow; any information in the comments that is relevant to the Q&A should be edited into the appropriate posts. You should not count on comments sticking around.

Comment: You've been a member of SO for 5+ years by your profile, with quite a few questions and answers, dating back to 2010. How have you remained ignorant of Meta.SO for that period of time?

Comment: I'm not sure what "life" you expect such comments as "Whomever wrote that should be brought to justice" (which appears to be the 100+ voted one you're referring to) brings to a post. That's one of the more sane sounding ones. Others appear semi-amusing, but ultimately, they were all massive noise and were deleted appropriately. In short - no - they won't be undeleted.

Comment: Nicolas Bolas, I never entered into a dispute before. This is the first time. I normally try to avoid the dispute even if the other person is wrong.

Comment: "I feel it is less maintainable".  That needs to be discussed on SO???  Please don't ask the obvious and we won't have to put up with the obvious comments either.

Comment: Hans Passant, Atleast 46 people think otherwise.

Comment: @Jean - now that you complained, I guarantee you that if they were all restored immediately, the *meta-effect* would kick into overdrive and they all would be flagged as *not constructive* or something else to get them removed again. What would you do then? Dispute again? If this is the first time you felt like disputing then your priorities are messed up. As it is, the entire question and all the answers are now going to come under intense scrutiny. Let me go see what all the fuss is about! ;-)

Comment: Jarrod Roberson, I am disputing because the moderator deleted well received comments on a whim on an inactive question when his job there was only to resolve the minor dispute regarding tags(which by the way, got resolved by itself without any intervention - when the reason for deletion was posted as a comment). 

Sure, I would take a chance and request the moderators to restore it and leave the fate of comments to the community.

Answer (score 15):

> The comments were giving life to the question.

Questions are not intended to have "life". Questions get answered, and that's it.

Comments exist to help improve the question in some way. Any comments that are not to those ends are ephemeral. And even those that are to that end are ephemeral.

> There wasn't any edit summary posted by editors who removed the disputed tag.

A person told you in a comment (that remains undeleted) why the tag was removed. Granted, it was a comment made one minute after you changed it back, but your change-back happened only four minutes after he undid it.

> (Add a feature so that users are forced to write a summary)

*Absolutely not.* Summaries are nice where appropriate, but in many cases, the change is self-justifying.

Comment: How do I agree to "disputes about its content are being resolved"  so that lock will be removed?

Comment: @Jean: In this case, as nothing more needs to be done, just let it expire naturally.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Oh, those expire by themselves? Is there a time limit documented somewhere? I assumed a diamond had to remove the lock.

Comment: @NathanTuggy See [What is a “locked” post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post). My guess is that lock was put in place for 24h, but we cannot know until after it expires naturally.